# how to count distinct elements of an array which contains different values that are strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, stl, compare

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
void solve()
{
    int n,cnt;
    cin >> n;
    string s,root="";
    vector<string>x;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        sort(s.begin(),s.end());
        for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++)
        {
            if(s[i] != s[i+1])
            {
                root+=s[i];
            }
        }
        x.push_back(root);
        root="";
    }
    cnt=0;
    for(int j=1; j<x.size(); j++)
    {
        if(x[j]!=(x[j-1]))
        {
           cnt++;
        }

        //cout << x[j] <<" ";
    }
     cout << cnt+1;
    
   
}
int main()
{
    solve();
}
```

`here i wanted to compare the strings as they were same or not. i wanted to print how many distinct strings there are

i tried to store the strings in a array of strings.help me solve this problem.`

Comment: Side notes: (1) [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) (2) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: An easy way looks like using [`std::set<std::string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

Comment: My favorite one liner: `auto count_distinct_entires = std::set{container.begin(), conteiner.end()}.size();`

Comment: Is it normal you sort your word? Do you want to count distinct anagram?

Comment: What is the problem?  Does this code work?  If not, how does it fail?

Comment: Judging by our code, you consider "ab", "ba", and "aab" to be "the same"?

Comment: here is the problem link @Jarod42 https://codeforces.com/contest/975/problem/A

Comment: yes they all are same @molbdnilo

Comment: @DrewDormann it shows wrong answer for some test cases

Comment: You don't sort `x`, so you cannot apply (your own version of )`std::unique` on it.

Comment: @Jarod42 thanks a lot,,after sorting it got accepted.

Answer (score 0):

this can be accepted

```
#include<iostream>
#include<set>
#include<string>

void solve()
{
    int n,cnt;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::set<std::set<char>> st;
    std::string s;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        std::cin >> s;
        std::set<char> t{s.begin(),s.end()};
        st.insert(t);
    }
    std::cout << st.size();
}
int main()
{
    solve();
}
```

use set to store unique letter of the string as a root,
then use another set to store different root

Comment: https://codeforces.com/contest/975/submission/198647431

Comment: even shorter: `root.emplace(s.begin(), s.end());`

Comment: You should **never** recommend the use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I just copy it from his code haha